# Regex to match "a string of length less than X resides between two ">" symbols"

Tags: bash, notepad++, regex

The have text in this form:

> >xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> >xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> xxxxxxxxxxx
>
> >

I need regex to match all `>xxx...` if there is less than, say a 100, amount of `x` in between `>` symbols. How can I do this?

The actual problem is: "smalt.c:334 ERROR: sequence too short to be hashed"
when trying to index fasta file with reference sequences of multiple viruses. It worked before, when only longer sequences were present in the file.

I haven't found a solution for the smalt error (and even if I would, I would prefer to run it first with default settings), so

I need to remove all the shorter reference sequences from the reference file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `grep` to give you only the parts of the file where there are more than 100 characters in between `>` and write the results into a new file (which then should work with fasta):

```
grep -Pzo '>[^>]{100,}' fasta.txt > fasta_wo_short_genes.txt
```

explanation:

- `-P` tells grep to accept pearl regular expressions (for some reason, I could not get it to work with the normal grep regular expressions)
- `z` tells grep to see the whole file as one big line
- `o` tells grep to output only the matching parts (otherwise, because of the `z` flag it would always output the whole file if it finds any match at all)

the regular expression:

- `>` the character separating your virus gene sequences
- `[^>]` matches any character except `>`
- `{100,}` matches 100 or more repetitions of the previous expression (in this case `[^>]`)

Comment: could you then please accept my answer? (click on the hollow check mark below the voting buttons to the left of the answer). Very much appreciated.